# Shiny - renaming factors in reactive data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app that queries an SQL database so the user can ggplot the data. I would like the user to be able to rename factors manually but am struggling to get going. Here is an example of what I want to do:

ui.R

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Reactive factor label"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Input wafer ID:"), value = NULL),

      actionButton("do", "Search wafer"),
      textInput("text", label = h3("Factor name to change"), value = ""),
      textInput("text", label = h3("New factor name"), value = ""),
      actionButton("do2", "Change name")

       ),

    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("waf"), 
      verbatimTextOutput("que"), 
      verbatimTextOutput("pos"),
      dataTableOutput(outputId="tstat")
    )
  )
)
)
```

server.R

```
# Create example data

Name <- factor(c("Happy", "New", "Year"))
Id <- 1:3

dd <- data.frame(Id, Name)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "dd", dd)
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...)

wq = data.frame()
sq = data.frame()


shinyServer(function(input, output){

  # create data frame to store reactive data set from query
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame()

  # Wait for user to search
  d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

  # Reactive SQL query
  a <- reactive({ paste0("Select * from dd where Id=",d()) })
  wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

  # Check outputs
  output$waf <- renderPrint(input$wafer)
  output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 
  output$pos <- renderPrint( wq()[1,1] )

  # observe d() so that data is not added until user presses action button  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(d())) {
      sq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

      # add query to reactive data frame
      values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), sq())
    }
  })

  output$tstat <- renderDataTable({
    data <- values$df
  })

})
```

In static R I would normally use data table to rename factors i.e.:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[Name=="Happy", Name:="Sad"]
```

But I'm not sure how to go about this with a reactiveValues i.e. `values$df`.

I have read this ([R shiny: How to get an reactive data frame updated each time pressing an actionButton without creating a new reactive data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716868/r-shiny-how-to-get-an-reactive-data-frame-updated-each-time-pressing-an-actionb)). This lead me to try this but it doesn't do anything (even no error):

```
observeEvent(input$do2, {
    DT <- data.table(values$df) 
    DT[Name == input$text1, Name := input$text2]
    values$df <- data.frame(values$df)

  })
```

Perhaps there is a way around this..maybe there is a way to use an action button to "lock in" the data as a new data frame, which can then be used to rename?

Sorry for such a long winded question. My real app is much longer and more complex. I have tried to strip it down.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20201070/2679518  If your `data.frame` is itself a reactive object you will not be able to change the names within the `data.frame` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works but there are a few issues in your app.

In `ui.R`, both `textInput` have the same `id`, they need to be different so you can refer to them in the `server.R`. In the `observeEvent` you posted, you refer to `input$text1` and `input$text2` so you should change the `id` of the `textInputs` to `text1` and `text2`.

In the `observeEvent` you posted, the last line should be `values$df <- as.data.frame(DT)`, otherwise it does not change anything.

Comment: Ah ha! Silly mistakes! Thank you very much.