# How to read uploaded file via Flexdashboard and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I want to create a web app using flexdashboard so that people can upload their CSV and see the visualization.

Right now, I am using a R markdown with flexdashboard template. Here is the file upload code.

```
{r, echo = FALSE}
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                    multiple = TRUE,
                   accept = c("text/csv",
                            "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                            ".csv"))
```

My question is: in this .rmd notebook, how can I access users' uploaded file and read it as dataframe?

Comment: You're missing server logic to handle the event when a file is uploaded. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502250/2516746) for more.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, is that possible to achieve my goal using .rmd instead of .r? The post you shared use .r.

Comment: Try my example I answered below.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know of is to do something like:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)

fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
          multiple = TRUE,
          accept = c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv")
)

values <- reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)

observeEvent(input$file1, {
  values$df_data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
})


renderTable(values$df_data)

```
````

You can really do whatever you'd like in that `observeEvent` expression (i.e. data validation, filter, transform, etc.).

Comment: Oh thank you so much! So basically, ```values$df_data```  is our variables or dataframe.

Comment: Exactly! Any time someone updates that input file, that reactive value gets updated, and thus any reactive expression/observer that depends on `values$df_data` will get updated and re-rendered as needed (like the `renderTable(values$df_data)` in this example.