# How to update a dataframe in R Shiny with user input

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I want to update a dataframe with user input in an R Shiny app. The user selects a row of data, and then chooses the value to update the Species column with using `selectInput`. The updates need to accumulate each time, i.e., the new updates update the previously updated data. I tried using `reactiveValues` as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502250/4380278), but couldn't get it to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(tidyverse)

iris_df = iris %>% 
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    Species = as.character(Species)
    )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  navbarPage(
    "HELP!", 
    tabPanel(
      "Iris",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("update_species", "Update species", choices = c("Rose", "Daffodil"))
        ),
        mainPanel(fluidRow(reactableOutput("iris")))
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$update_species, {
      iris_df = iris_df %>% 
        mutate(Species = case_when(id == selected_row() ~ input$update_species, TRUE ~ Species))
  })
  
  selected_row = reactive(getReactableState("iris", "selected"))
  
  output$iris = renderReactable({
    reactable(
      iris_df,
      selection = "single",
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that the `observeEvent` is triggered by `input$update_species` which results in an error if no row was selected in which case `selected_row()` is `NULL`. To prevent that you could add a `req(selected_row())` or use `selected_row()` to trigger the `observeEvent` as I do in my code below.

Next, as you already realized you need a `reactiveVal` or a `reactiveValues` to actually update the dataframe inside the `observeEvent` based on the user choice.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(tidyverse)

iris_df <- iris %>%
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    Species = as.character(Species)
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "HELP!",
    tabPanel(
      "Iris",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("update_species", "Update species", choices = unique(iris_df$Species))
        ),
        mainPanel(fluidRow(reactableOutput("iris")))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  iris_df <- reactiveVal(iris_df)

  observeEvent(selected_row(), {
    iris_df(iris_df() %>%
      mutate(Species = case_when(id == selected_row() ~ input$update_species, TRUE ~ Species)))
  })

  selected_row <- reactive(getReactableState("iris", "selected"))

  output$iris <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      iris_df(),
      selection = "single",
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is an example output after updating rows 1, 4 and 7:

[image]